# I don't know how to get basic collision working

Tags: love2d

I'm new to Love2D and Lua but so far it's been going well. I'm trying to make a simple game but so far I haven't been able to find anything on collision besides having the player not scroll of screen. I've been trying to use this

```
function CheckCollision(x1,y1,w1,h1, x2,y2,w2,h2)
return x1 < x2+w2 and
     x2 < x1+w1 and
     y1 < y2+h2 and
     y2 < y1+h1
end
```

But I'm not entirely sure how to use it as each time I tried nothing in the program changed. Please help?

I'm not too familiar with this site, sorry. I changed it but it still doesn't work.

```
tree = {x = 20, y = 20, speed = 0, img = nil }

tree.img = love.graphics.newImage("assets/tree.png")

function CheckCollision(x1,y1,w1,h1, x2,y2,w2,h2)
  return x1 < x2+w2 or
     x2 < x1+w1 or
     y1 < y2+h2 or
     y2 < y1+h1
end

function tree_update(dt)
    if CheckCollision(crs.x, crs.y, crs.img:getWidth(), crs.img:getHeight(),    tree.x, tree.y, tree.img:getWidth(), tree.img:getHeight()) then
    love.graphics.print("It touched the thing", love.graphics:getWidth()/2-        50, love.graphics:getHeight()/2-10)
   end
   end

   function tree_draw()
    love.graphics.draw(tree.img, tree.x, tree.y)
   end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return statement should be using `or` instead of `and` as you want it to return that it has collided when any of the statements are true.

```
function CheckCollision(x1,y1,w1,h1, x2,y2,w2,h2)
  return x1 < x2+w2 or
     x2 < x1+w1 or
     y1 < y2+h2 or
     y2 < y1+h1
end
```

There's also a collision feature in Love2D called "[Contacts](https://love2d.org/wiki/Contact)" that may help with things like collisions.